# Can't access my webcam with html5?

Tags: javascript, webcam

I am trying to use the following code to take a snapshot using getUserMedia, problem is the webcam activates but I can't see the image stream, it doesn't work.

Is it possible it's because the page is not hosted anywhere, I heard that getUserMedia only works on secure sites using https...

Here is the code, it's fairly simple:

```js
(function() {

  var streaming = false,
      video        = document.querySelector('#video'),
      canvas       = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
      photo        = document.querySelector('#photo'),
      startbutton  = document.querySelector('#startbutton'),
      width = 320,
      height = 0;

  navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);

  navigator.getMedia(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },
    function(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
      } else {
        var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      }
      video.play();
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    }
  );

  video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  }

  startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

})();
```

```html
<body>
<video id="video"></video>
<button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img id="photo" alt="photo">
```

Comment: The browser maybe blocking access to the camera. In chrome - look in the address bar. There should be a camera icon. You need to allow the site to access the camera. Firefox wont allow anything but HTTPS connections and Edge - well it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` tag is commented. That's why the `photo` variable could not find the DOM and reference it. Uncomment the last line in html and i think it will solve your problem. [**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/b021qz3u/)

Comment: can you run the demo I attached ?

Comment: Yes, I can run the jsfiddle but It doesn't work for me when I am running it from my html file, really weird.

Comment: can you share the error log when running the code in your local environment ?

Comment: sure, how do I do that? I am kind of a newbie.

Comment: This is what it shows me in console:Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/b19c29aa-a6ce-4a5f-841c-550e934b9d69
ChurriEN.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: Are you running the `html` file directly ? You need to serve the html page using a http server, instead of opening it directly to a browser

Comment: Yes I'm running it through notepad++, how can I set a http server?

Comment: it's not dependent on editor. if you are in linux environment, run the following command from your project directory
`$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`
This will expose your project at `localhost:8080`. now, if your file name is `foo.html`, enter `localhost:8080/foo.html` in browser address bar at hit enter

Comment: I'm not in a linux enviroment, I'm on W10 sorry

Comment: install apache or some other server. You will find enough resource on internet about how to setup a web server in windows environment